# Hi, How do I run the equivalent using pymongo? cfg = rs.conf() db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

1>How can I run the equivalent using pymongo?

a>

```
cfg = rs.conf()
```

b>

```
db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()
```

2>Using PyMongo, how can I get the details of other replica sets CLI output in the created clusters .
(Note:I have already successfully created cluster.Just I am writing a python script in primary to check the outputs of `rs.conf()` and `db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()` in all the replica sets inside cluster and parse the output.)

Any help on this regard is greatly appreciable.

Comment: were you able to do this? I am also stuck with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The replica set configuration is stored in the "local" database in a collection called "system.replset" so the equivalent of `rs.conf()` would be `db.system.replset.findOne()` when db is `local` or its equivalent `find_one()` in Python.

db.printSlaveReplicationInfo() is a big more involved, but you can get all of that information in the `local` database as well.

It may be easier to get it via admin database command `replSetGetStatus` which returns a document containing oplog information for each member of the replica set, along with other details.  Python MongoDB driver `pymongo` [provides a method to run commands](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command), so you can run it against the `admin` DB and parse out the output for information about where each member of the replica set is relative to the primary.

Comment: Thanks Neil and Asya..rs.conf() check is needed for me to find out the members of cluster but as Asya Specified I cannot depend upon replSetGetStatus(rs.status()) because my motive is to  write a python script to find out the time before sync happened between all the replica set of cluster..So that's why I am depending upon db.printSlaveReplicationInfo() as it specified the time before sync happened between all three cluster..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "before the sync hapens" - all these variants will return the same information about the cluster and state of replication.

Comment: Actually I wrote a script which is writing data continously to primary using pymongo in MongoDb.
rs0:SECONDARY> db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()
source:   172.22.105.57:27017
         syncedTo: Fri Apr 25 2014 02:46:43 GMT-0400 (EDT)
                 = 254617 secs ago (70.73hrs)
source:   172.22.105.58:27017
         syncedTo: Fri Apr 25 2014 02:46:43 GMT-0400 (EDT)
                 = 254617 secs ago (70.73hrs)

Answer (score 0):

I'm basically going to give you a hint rather than directly answer it, because the full answer is to simply code it. But you probably are unaware that you can do this simple thing in the shell:

```js
> db.printSlaveReplicationInfo
function () {
    var startOptimeDate = null;

    function getReplLag(st) {
        assert( startOptimeDate , "how could this be null (getReplLag startOptimeDate)"     );
        print("\tsyncedTo: " + st.toString() );
        var ago = (startOptimeDate-st)/1000;
        var hrs = Math.round(ago/36)/100;
        print("\t" + Math.round(ago) + " secs (" + hrs + " hrs) behind the primary ");
    };

    function getMaster(members) {
        var found;
        members.forEach(function(row) {
            if (row.self) {
                found = row;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (found) {
            return found;
        }
    };

    function g(x) {
        assert( x , "how could this be null (printSlaveReplicationInfo gx)" )
        print("source: " + x.host);
        if ( x.syncedTo ){
            var st = new Date( DB.tsToSeconds( x.syncedTo ) * 1000 );
            getReplLag(st);
        }
        else {
            print( "\tdoing initial sync" );
        }
    };

    function r(x) {
        assert( x , "how could this be null (printSlaveReplicationInfo rx)" );
        if ( x.state == 1 || x.state == 7 ) {  // ignore primaries (1) and arbiters (7)
            return;
        }

        print("source: " + x.name);
        if ( x.optime ) {
            getReplLag(x.optimeDate);
        }
        else {
            print( "\tno replication info, yet.  State: " + x.stateStr );
        }
    };

    var L = this.getSiblingDB("local");

    if (L.system.replset.count() != 0) {
        var status = this.adminCommand({'replSetGetStatus' : 1});
        startOptimeDate = getMaster(status.members).optimeDate;
        status.members.forEach(r);
    }
    else if( L.sources.count() != 0 ) {
        startOptimeDate = new Date();
        L.sources.find().forEach(g);
    }
    else {
        print("local.sources is empty; is this db a --slave?");
        return;
    }
}
```

I love [REPL's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), and much like python's own famous REPL you can just get a dump of what the implemented function does.

Simples.

Comment: A great thanks Neil and Asya as it helped me to get answer of my question..rs.conf() check is needed for me to find out the members of cluster but as Asya Specified I cannot depend upon replSetGetStatus(rs.status()) because my motive is to  write a python script to find out the time before sync happened between all the replica sets of cluster..So that's why I am depending upon db.printSlaveReplicationInfo() as it gives the time before last sync happened between all replica sets of cluster.